# js onclick function is not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am tring to call a functiion on click of a button . I included jquery on the top but function is not working . please look at my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    function check_me(){
        alert(0123);
   }
 });
  </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <button id="ids" value="123" onClick="check_me();" >click me </button>
   </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put the function outside of document ready

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

 });
 function check_me(){
        alert(0123);
   }
  </script>
```

Comment: yes it is working just like  i want but why it was not working before ...??

Comment: its not working Because the function is not available in the global scope

Answer (score 2):

You have include the jQuery library but you are still using javascript. You need to bind click event as shown below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    //selecting jquery using id
    $('#ids').click(function(){
        alert(0123);
   });
 });
  </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <button id="ids" value="123" >click me </button>
   </body>
</html>
```

**[More Information on jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

**Note** - Please make sure that you have unique id for each element for which you are using jquery.

Comment: i know that but i want make it work onclick of button without using button id

Comment: in that case you need to put function outside `document.ready` as suggested by Osama Jetawe. But then why you are using jquery here?

Answer (score 0):

Keep your check_me function out of document ready. Your script should be:

```
<script>
    function check_me(){
        alert(0123);
   }
  </script>
```

only.